# Word for "mindlessly entertain"

Tags: synonyms, vocabulary

Sometimes I get done working and my mind is utterly exhausted. I want something to entertain me mindlessly.

Is there a good verb to describe this action?

Comment: It's called television

Comment: Hmm television is not a verb. How can we verb it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to veg out. Or you can say you're looking for brain candy.

Comment: _brain candy_ was the first thing that came to my mind, too.

Comment: I really like brain candy

Answer (score 2):

[Take one's mind off](http://www.wordreference.com/thesaurus/take%20one's%20mind%20off) is a useful expression:

> - turn one's attention from, divert, distract.
> - to do something to help you forget about something else.
>
> When she studies hard for tests, Tam likes to take her mind off her topic every few hours and go for a walk.

Source:http://www.idiomeanings.com/idioms/take-your-mind-off/

Answer (score 1):

to divert / to distract

"I was like a boy playing on the sea-shore, and diverting myself now and then finding a smoother pebble or a prettier shell than ordinary, whilst the great ocean of truth lay all undiscovered before me." Isaac Newton

I wonder if you meant on who does it unintentionally or a diversion.

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/divert

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/divert

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/divert

Comment: In my condition it's more so after the work and I'm in an exhausted state. I'll update the question